# Using HTTP Status Codes for Rails AJAX Error Handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

Hoping someone can shed some light on a problem I have.

I have a Rails 3.0.7 app using JQuery 1.5.2. I'm using unobtrusive Javascript (ujs) to call a controller function (destroy). I want to use HTTP status codes in my respond_with block to trigger Ajax Error handling if something goes wrong with the operation. The following is not working for me:

```
  #controller
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :js

    before_filter :load_all_books, :only => [:index, :destroy]

    def index
      respond_with @books
    end

    def destroy
      if request.delete?
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])

        unless @book.in_use?
          @book.destroy
          respond_with(@books)
        else
          respond_with(@books) do |format|
            format.js {render :status => :locked }
          end
        end
      end
    end

    private
    def load_all_books
      @books = Book.order('created_at desc')
    end
  end


  #books/index.html.erb
  <%= link_to "delete", book_path(book), :remote => :true, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure", :class => "remove-link" %>


  #books/destroy.js.erb
  jQuery(function($) {

      $('.remove-link').bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
        alert('success');
        });

      $('.remove-link').bind("ajax:error", function(evt, xhr, status, error){
        alert('error');
        });
  });
```

If the operation is successful then the ajax:success callback is triggered correctly. However if the operation is unsuccessful and a:locked (423) status is returned the ajax:error callback is not triggered.
Any ideas why this doesn't work and how can I trigger the ajax:error callback?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I'm tying to handle this in an unconventional way?

How do other people trigger custom ajax:errors?